# Best DevOps use of AWS Auto-scaling Groups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-deployment, devops, autoscaling

I've been working on a DevOps pipeline for an application hosted on AWS. I want to make an improvement to my current setup, but I'm not sure the best way to go about doing it. My current set up is as follows:

- ASG behind ELB
- Desired capacity: 1
- Min capacity: 1
- Max capacity: 1
- Code deployment process:

  1. move deployable to S3
  2. terminate instance in ASG
  3. new instance is automatically provisioned
  4. new instance pulls down deployable in user data

The problem with this setup is that the environment is down from when the instance is terminated to when the new instance has been completely provisioned.

I've been thinking about ways that I can improve this process to eliminate the downtime, and I've come up with two possible solutions:

**SOLUTION #1:**

- ASG behind ELB
- Desired capacity: 1
- Min capacity: 1
- Max capacity: 2
- Code deployment process:

  1. move deployable to S3
  2. launch new instance into ASG
  3. new instance pulls down deployable in user data
  4. terminate instance with old deployable

With this solution, there is always at least one instance capable of serving requests in the ASG. The problem is, ASGs don't seem to support a simple operation of manually calling on it to spin up a new instance. (They only launch new instances when the scaling policies call for it.) You can attach existing instances to the group, but this causes the desired capacity value to increase, which I don't want.

**SOLUTION #2:**

- ASG behind ELB
- Desired capacity: 2
- Min capacity: 2
- Max capacity: 2
- Code deployment process:

  1. move deployable to S3
  2. terminate instance-A
  3. new instance-A is automatically provisioned
  4. instance-A pulls down new deployable by user data script
  5. terminate instance-B
  6. new instance-B is automatically provisioned
  7. instance-B pulls down new deployable by user data script

Just as with the previous solution, there is always at least one instance available to serve requests. The problem is, there are usually two instances, even when only one is needed. Additionally, the code deployment process seems needlessly complicated.

So which is better: solution #1, solution #2, or some other solution I haven't thought of yet? Also a quick disclaimer: I understand that I'm using ASGs for something other than their intended purpose, but it seemed the best way to implement automated code deployments along AWS's "EC2 instances are cattle" philosophy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term you are looking for is "zero-downtime deployment."

> The problem is, ASGs don't seem to support a simple operation of manually calling on it to spin up a new instance. (They only launch new instances when the scaling policies call for it.) You can attach existing instances to the group, but this causes the desired capacity value to increase, which I don't want.

If you change desired capacity yourself (e.g. via an API call), the Auto Scaling Group will automatically launch an extra instance for you. For example, here is a simple way to implement zero-downtime deployment for your Auto Scaling Group (ASG):

1. Run the ASG behind an Elastic Load Balancer (ELB).
2. Initially, the desired capacity is 1, so you have just one EC2 Instance in the ASG.
3. To deploy new code, you first create a new launch configuration with the new code (e.g. new AMI or new User Data).
4. Next, you change the desired capacity from 1 to 2. The ASG will automatically launch a new EC2 Instance with the new launch configuration.
5. Once the new EC2 Instance is up and running and registered in your ELB, you change the desired capacity from 2 back to 1, and the ASG will automatically terminate the older EC2 Instance.

You can implement this manually or use existing tools to do it for you, such as:

- Define your ASG using [CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) and specify an [UpdatePolicy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-updatepolicy.html) that does a zero-downtime rolling deployment.
- Define your ASG using [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) and use the `create_before_destroy` lifecycle property to do a zero-downtime (sort-of) blue-green deployment [as described here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/terraform-tool/7Gdhv1OAc80/iNQ93riiLwAJ).
- Define your ASG using [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) and use the `serial` keyword to do [rolling upgrades](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/guide_rolling_upgrade.html).
- Use the [aws-ha-release](https://github.com/colinbjohnson/aws-missing-tools/tree/master/aws-ha-release) script.

You can learn more about the [trade-offs between tools like Terraform, CloudFormation, Ansible, Chef, and Puppet here](https://blog.gruntwork.io/why-we-use-terraform-and-not-chef-puppet-ansible-saltstack-or-cloudformation-7989dad2865c).

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer! I think this approach is what I was looking for. Using the "Desired Capacity" property to manually control the scaling was the magical missing piece for me. I've always thought of it as a property you set when you first provision the ASG and then don't change subsequently. It is unfortunate that the added complexity of waiting until the new instance is in service before decrementing the "Desired Capacity" is necessary. But it's a viable solution!

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is a DevOps pipeline and not a production environment, what you are describing sounds like a blue/green deployment scenario in which you want to be able to switch between environments without downtime. I think the best answer is largely specific to your requirements (which we don't 100% know), but a guide like [The DOs and DON'Ts of Blue/Green Deployment](https://cloudnative.io/blog/2015/02/the-dos-and-donts-of-bluegreen-deployment/) will be beneficial in finding the best way to achieve your goals, whether it is #1, #2, or something else.

Comment: My understanding of the blue/green technique is that you use it when you want to verify that the newly deployed artifact is functional in the environment before directing production traffic to it. I'm just looking for a way to perform a routine deployment (ie, the newly deployed artifact doesn't necessarily need to be fully functional, as the deployment could be to the development environment) without downtime. That being said, the blue/green technique probably could be used here (use two ASGs and alternate traffic) but it seems a bit like overkill if there's a way to achieve it with just one.

Comment: Agreed - I think it came to mind when you wanted to not have any downtime. You can use the "Desired Capacity" of the ASG to take manual control of the scaling. You could have a script that increases the desired capacity to 2 (causing a new instance to start) and then back to 1 after it starts. A Termination Policy set to OldestInstance would terminate the original instance leaving just the new one.

Comment: I think that will do the trick!! Using the "Desired Capacity" property to manually control the scaling was the magical missing piece for me. I've always thought of it as a property you set when you first provision the ASG and then don't change subsequently. Thank you!